# Determine whenever block/multiple blocks are in air in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Code:

```
class Block
{
    internal Vector3Int Position;
    internal bool IsInAir;
}
class BlockChecker
{
    List<Block> Block = new List<Block>();
    void Update()
    {
        //Here check if multiple blocks are flying.
    }
}
```

How can I check if multiple block are flying?

Example:
Ground is at position `x = 0, y = 6, z = 0` and there are multiple blocks connected to each other at position `x = 0, y = 8, z = 0` and `x = 0, y = 9, z = 0` how can i determine that there isnt any block under it and set `IsInAir` to true for every connected block and if there is atleast one block under these blocks at position `x = 0, y = 7, z = 0`, set `IsInAir` for every connected block to false?

Comment: You need to arrange your blocks in a graph-like data structure which lets you determine which other blocks each block is connected to. Once you have them arranged that way you will need an [algorithm that traverses the structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) and checks if any of the blocks is connected to the ground.

Comment: Can you write an example?

Comment: @MateuszJopek Sure, add your blocks, have them locate nearby, add those blocks to each of them so they know which block they are touching.  Then when you want to know if a block is in the air you check if any of them are touching the ground based off of all its neighbor blocks, kinda like a breadth first search.

Comment: Would these be rectilinear cuboid blocks of equal dimensions *a la* a certain game that every person in existence has heard of? I smell voxel. Secure the area!

Comment: I made an algorithm that checks if they are touching ground but how can I locate them nearby?